# Mongoose populate subdoc

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have an `orderSchema` that has a `subdoc productOrder`:

```
const paymentTrans = require('./PaymentTrans').schema;
const productOrder = require('./ProductOrder').schema;

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    orderId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
    userId : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    productOrder: [productOrder],
    totalPerOrder: {type: Number, default:''},
    paymentTrans: [paymentTrans]
}, { timestamps: true });

const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);

module.exports = Order;
```

**porductOrder Schema**

```
const productOrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    sku: { type: String, default: '' },
    name: { type: String, default: '' },
    quantity: { type: Number, default: '' },
    price: { type: Number, default: '' },
    total: { type: Number, default: '' }
});

const ProductOrder = mongoose.model('ProductOrder', productOrderSchema);

module.exports = ProductOrder;
```

I wish to get `productOrder` from `order` (`orderSchema`):

**tried these**

```
Order.findById(req.body.id)
        .exec(function (err, products) {
            var opts = {
                path: 'productOrder',
                model: 'ProductOrder'
            };

            Order.populate(products, opts, function (ree, products) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(products));
            });

            res.render('store/cart', {
                title: 'MyCart',
                angularApp: 'storeApp',
                products: products
            });
        });
```

Where `req.body.id` is the `orderId` and the `object` in `console` looks like this: (sorry, `WebStorm` no Copy/Paste from console)

[image: console.log(JSON.stringify(products)]

**Another way I tried**

```
Order.findById(req.body.id, function (err, products) {
        var opts = [
            { path: 'productOrder',  model: 'ProductOrder' }
        ]

        Order.populate(products, opts, function (err, products) {
            console.log(products);
        })
    })
```

**And yet another**

```
Order.find({ _id: req.body.id, userId: req.user._id })
        .populate({
            path: 'productOrder',
            populate: {
                path: 'productOrder',
                model: 'ProductOrder'
            }

        })
        .exec(function (err, productOrder) {
            //products.forEach(function(elem){
                console.log("products = " + JSON.stringify(productOrder));
            //});

            console.log("REQ._ID " + req.body.id);
            res.render('store/cart', {
                title: 'MyCart',
                angularApp: 'storeApp',
                products: productOrder
            });
        });
```

They all end up giving me the entire `doc` of the order.
How can I get just the products of the order? (`productOrder`)
Thanx

Comment: why don't you use reference to order and keep it as subdoc like you do it with user: userId : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}?

Comment: @IgnatGalkin, I know it can be done that way as well...tried understanding which is better...couldn't find anything...Ideas??

Answer (score 1):

You may use `select` function and then populate as following

```
Order.findOne({ _id: req.body.id})
    .select('-_id productOrder')
    .populate('productOrder')
    .exec(function (err, orderObj) {
      if(!err) {
        var productOrder = orderObj.productOrder;
        //products.forEach(function(elem){
            console.log("products = " + JSON.stringify(productOrder));
        //});

        console.log("REQ._ID " + req.body.id);
        res.render('store/cart', {
            title: 'MyCart',
            angularApp: 'storeApp',
            products: productOrder
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: You can also skip the `populate()`: subdocuments are included in the parent document, they aren't stored separately.

Comment: @robertklep, funny enough the `res.render` changes `view` but `URL` stays the same, thus, if I` F5` the current screen, its goes back to `carts`...any idea why?? I have used this code 10s of times without any problems...