# node res.render changes view but not url

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I am sending an `id` from a `jade view` to its `controller`(backend), the controller then queries `mongodb` and the result is sent to a new `jade view`-`angular`.
The results & view appear but `URL` stays the same (previous view), thus if I `F5` the current view, it reloads the previous view.
So the route is: `view->node->angular`
Ideas?

**jade launcher view**

```
form(method="post")
    input(type="hidden" name="id" value=cart._id)
    input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value=_csrf)
    button.btn.product.btn-primary(type='submit', id=cart._id class='')
```

**controller**

```
exports.pushCart = (req, res) => {

if (passport.isAuthenticated) {

    Order.findOne({ _id: req.body.id})
        .select('-_id productOrder')
        .exec(function (err, orderObj) {
            if(!err) {
                var productOrder = orderObj.productOrder;

                res.render('store/cart', {
                    title: 'MyCart',
                    angularApp: 'storeApp',
                    products: productOrder
                });
            }
        });

} else {
    res.redirect('/login');
}
};
```

[Mongoose populate subdoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39570938/mongoose-populate-subdoc)

Comment: You have to use `res.redirect('/some/path')` if you want the URL to change.

Comment: @idbehold, not in this case, `res.render()` will render the view with data passed to it, `res.redirect()` will redirect a user to another page (at which point the request starts over)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can either render a view in response to the POST request (the URL in the browser will remain the same) or you can redirect which will change the URL in the browser. You cannot do both from the server-side.

Comment: You could (on the client-side) use the HTML5 History API to change the URL automatically when the page loads. But you cannot accomplish what you want purely with node on the server-side.

Comment: @idbehold, that is my problem

Comment: Why not simply change the form's `method` to `"GET"`. Then the browser would change the URL automatically for you.

Comment: @idbehold, the problem isn't the form, that worx, the issue is with the `res.render` executed after the `query`, I need to pass a `JSON array` to `angular`

Comment: why do you care if the URL changes?

Comment: @idbehold, I am actually trying to reload items into `localStorage` upon user selection, if `URL` does not change any `F5` will re-reload the cart thus  user ending up with more items in `localStorage` then initially expected

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect ,if you want the URL to change
like this

```
 res.redirect('/some/path')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass information while changing the URL you have to use session in order to transfer the data between pages.

[connect-flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash) is very popular to use with passport for temporary session data transfer.

`res.redirect('/store/card')` should be used in order to change the URL but it does not accept object to pass. That's the reason we use session in order to pass the information.

Here is your code should look like;

```
app.post('/yourPostURL', function(req, res){
  // Auth and validate here, then
  // Set a flash message by passing the key, followed by the value, to req.flash().
  req.flash('success', 'Put anything here')
  res.redirect('/store/card');
});

app.get('/store/card', function(req, res){
  // Get an array of flash messages by passing the key to req.flash()
  res.render('store/card', { messages: req.flash('success') });
});
```