# URL does not change with res.render()

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I need to send list of apps after login to ejs template engine from server with expressjs. For that purpose, I am using `res.render()`. Even though it renders the specified file, it does not change the url. What should I do to redirect along with data and make changes to url.

routes.js

```
const loginUser = requie('../Controller/LoginController');
router.post('/login', loginUser);
```

LoginController.js

```
const loginUser = (req, res) => {
    /* login code */
   res.render('apps/app-list', {
     title: 'Application List',
     isLoggedIn: true
   });
};
```

After successfull login, it is rendering the contents of `apps/app-list`, but url is still `users/login`.

Comment: I think this question should answer yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620470/node-res-render-changes-view-but-not-url
Basically, if you want to change the url you should use res.redirect() and to pass objects with that you should use sessions. I use connect-flash, here is the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash

Comment: How can I send multiple values with `req.flash()`? @Cortoloman

Comment: I want to send data of  `get` request to ejs template along with `ifLoggedIn`. How can I achieve that? @Cortoloman

Comment: @SujayPrabhu did you achieve on how to consume data when use render in ejs template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to send data you should render a page, here is an example from a piece of my app:

```
app.get("/myfood", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    Food.find({}, (error, allfood) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error)
        } else {
            res.render("myfood", {food: allfood})
        }
    })
})
```

So I am sending all found food items with the get request. And you can send multiple objects. Just separate them with a comma.

As I said in a comment you can't do the same if you want to

> res.redirect()

So, in my app, I wanted to send a flash message when the user signs up. Here:

```
newUser.save()
  .then(user => {
       req.flash("sucess_msg", "Thank you for registering.")
       res.redirect("/login");
  })
```

You can search a bit on YouTube on how to use req.flash() there are a couple great tutorials. I learned about it from Brad Traversy, passport node app.

That's about all I can give you. req.flash() is defined in a global variable

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.sucess_msg = req.flash("sucess_msg");
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash("error_msg");
    res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
    next();
});
```

Try to do the same and maybe go from there. Hope you will be a step closer

Comment: Hi, res.redirect changes the content displayed to the screen BUT doesnt change the url why is that?

Answer (score 0):

you can do a redirect to your desired endpoint inside which you can render the required page.

```
res.redirect('/viewer');
//This will set the URL to <yourhost>/viewer

app.get("/viewer", function (req, res) {
    res.render('pages/viewer');
});
//This shall render the viewer page on this URL.

This will render your page and also show the URL you want.
```

Comment: Hi, when answering, it's better to adapt original code; your answer is totally another setting. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)